# Error in SQL Server 2005 Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, temp-tables

Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TmpFeesToRules1(Name varchar, LookupId int)

INSERT INTO dbo.TmpFeesToRules1(Name, LookupId)
SELECT DISTINCT Name, 0 FROM Lending.Fee
UNION SELECT DISTINCT Name, 0 FROM Lending.ApplicationFee

INSERT INTO dbo.tblLookup (LookupType, LookupCode, LookupDesc, EditFlag, DeletedFlag, DefaultFlag)
SELECT 'FEE_CODE', Name,  Name, 0, 0, 0
FROM dbo.TmpFeesToRules1

UPDATE dbo.TmpFeesToRules1
SET
    LookupId = L.LookupID
FROM
    dbo.tblLookup L
INNER JOIN dbo.TmpFeesToRules1 T ON T.Name = L.LookupDesc
WHERE
    L.LookupType = 'FEE_CODE'

CREATE TABLE dbo.TmpFeesToRules2(FeeId int, Name varchar)

INSERT INTO dbo.TmpFeesToRules2(FeeId, Name)
SELECT FeeId, Name FROM Lending.ApplicationFee

GO

UPDATE Lending.ApplicationFee 
SET Lending.ApplicationFee.FeeTypeId = T.LookupId
FROM dbo.TmpFeesToRules2 TT
INNER JOIN dbo.TmpFeesToRules1 T ON T.Name = TT.Name
WHERE Lending.ApplicationFee.FeeId = TT.FeeId

DROP TABLE dbo.TmpFeesToRules1
DROP TABLE dbo.TmpFeesToRules2
```

Here is the error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.TmpFeesToRules2'.
>   Execute failed, return code: 1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to do with `Go` or semicolons,

You are updating `Lending.ApplicationFee` but it doesn't appear in the `FROM` clause.

```
UPDATE Lending.ApplicationFee 
SET Lending.ApplicationFee.FeeTypeId = T.LookupId
FROM dbo.TmpFeesToRules2 TT
INNER JOIN dbo.TmpFeesToRules1 T ON T.Name = TT.Name
WHERE Lending.ApplicationFee.FeeId = TT.FeeId
```

I guess this should be something like

```
UPDATE Lending.ApplicationFee 
SET Lending.ApplicationFee.FeeTypeId = T.LookupId
FROM Lending.ApplicationFee join dbo.TmpFeesToRules2 TT ON <Some Condition>
INNER JOIN dbo.TmpFeesToRules1 T ON T.Name = TT.Name
WHERE Lending.ApplicationFee.FeeId = TT.FeeId
```

Comment: And I think this is where the error is :) in spite of all the CREATE/INSERT/GO debate

Comment: +1 I've deleted my input into that debate to avoid clouding the answer.

Comment: You should get a badge for that I think!

Comment: @Martin I didn't have enough votes to get that "delete your own post" badge, but up-voting you gave me Civic Duty lol, btw you don't work in Manchester do you?

Comment: Nope, no Manchester connections. It seems there's quite a few Martin Smiths about.

Comment: Figured it out. It actually had something to do with another part of the Database, but honestly, I can't even believe you found something like that. Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TmpFeesToRules2(FeeId int, Name varchar)

INSERT INTO dbo.TmpFeesToRules2(FeeId, Name)
SELECT FeeId, Name FROM Lending.ApplicationFee
```

you could just do:

```
SELECT FeeId, Name 
INTO dbo.TmpFeesToRules2 
FROM Lending.ApplicationFee
```

That will create and populate the table in one step

Comment: I don't think so. And I don't think the problem is in the GO. GO is not a SQL command per se, it just tells the tool to send the code to the database